# Working with PHP $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] variable when used in command line script

Tags: php

It seems as if I cannot use the `$_SERVER` vars in a command line script in PHP as the return seems to be blank? If this is the case then does anyone have a suggestion for getting the IP of the server I am running the script on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`SERVER_ADDR` is defined by the webserver as CGI environment variable, and depends upon which interface it listens to. A server might have multiple network addresses.

You can fetch it from either `ip addr` or `ifconfig`, preferrably looking for the eth0 interface (most common).

```
preg_match("/inet (addr:)?(?!127)(\d+(\.\d+){3})/", `ip addr`, $m);
```

Answer (score 0):

use grep command

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-get-an-ip-address-from-command-line-522676/